# Bounced emails with fuel sdk php

Tags: php, fuel-sdk

I'm trying to retrieve bounced mails with Fuel SDK PHP ET_BounceEvent object:

`require('ET_Client.php');
$myclient = new ET_Client();
$bounceevent = new ET_BounceEvent();
$bounceevent->authStub = $myclient;

$response = $bounceevent->get();
print_r($response);`

All seems to be Ok. But we noticed one problem.
Once data is retrieved, it becomes unavailable later. We can not retieve the same data for second time. For example: first run returns data, second/third/4th/... doesn't work for the same code.

Are there any posibility to make this data available for each time the code runs?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The underlying API supports the ability to retrieve all since the last batch and this option defaults to true when using the FuelSDK for PHP. To disable this, set the getSinceLastBatch property on the ET_BounceEvent to false. This will allow you to retrieve the same records if you make the same request multiple times.

Example:

```
$bounceevent = new ET_BounceEvent();
$bounceevent->authStub = $myclient;
$bounceevent->getSinceLastBatch = false;
```