# Fuel SDK - Subsequent ET_BounceEvent() calls with same parameters returns empty Results

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, c#, fuel-sdk, fuel

I'm using the C# Fuel SDK to fetch `BounceEvent`s created on a given date. On an initial request, I receive back a `GetReturn` with a `Status` of `true` and an expected batch of `APIObject`s in `Results`. However, if I repeat the request a second time with the same parameters, `Results` is empty:

```
var date = new DateTime(2014, 10, 01);

var filter = new ComplexFilterPart {
    LeftOperand = new SimpleFilterPart {
        Property = "EventDate",
        SimpleOperator = SimpleOperators.greaterThanOrEqual,
        DateValue = new[]{date}
    },
    LogicalOperator = LogicalOperators.AND,
    RightOperand = new SimpleFilterPart {
        Property = "EventDate",
        SimpleOperator = SimpleOperators.lessThan,
        DateValue = new[]{date.AddDays(1)}
    }
};

var etRequest = new ET_BounceEvent{
    AuthStub = new ET_Client(new NameValueCollection {{"clientId", "XXX"}, {"clientSecret", "XXX"}}),
    SearchFilter = filter
};

etRequest.Get().Dump();
```

This is potentially related to pagination, but it seems odd that that would apply since I'm creating a new `ET_BounceEvent` client between requests. (And if it is pagination-related, what parameter do I need to pass in to reset to the first page of results?)

This problem persists even if I remove the filter.

(This seems related to [ET_ClickEvent Get() does not return results consistently](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/48102/et-clickevent-get-does-not-return-results-consistently))

Comment: Another similar question: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/30784/bounced-emails-with-fuel-sdk-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GetSinceLastBatch property on tracking events defaults to True so after you retrieve the records, it keeps track and only returns new records when a subsequent call is made with the same criteria.

To disable it, set the GetSinceLastBatch property on ET_BounceEvent to false.

Example:

```
var etRequest = new ET_BounceEvent{
    AuthStub = new ET_Client(new NameValueCollection {{"clientId", "XXX"}, {"clientSecret", "XXX"}}),
    SearchFilter = filter,
    GetSinceLastBatch = false };
```